# Golang: Error while make test: signal: killed

Tags: go, makefile

I am getting this error while running make test on a Golang project:

```
signal: killed
FAIL <package name>
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

The same code was running perfectly fine until yesterday.
Note: I tried doing make test on other branches also but same result.

Comment: Maybe try running specific tests to figure out which one is causing a panic?

Comment: Does you project use cgo, and are you using Xcode8.3?

Comment: I'm hitting this error, and yeah, using cgo with xcode cli tools 8.3.  Did that introduce a problem?

Comment: Yes my project uses cgo. And I also have xcode 8.3 installed, but not using it in this project. @JimB

Comment: Seems to be a known issue: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19734

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE on 04/27/2017:**

The new Go1.8.1 (released 2017/04/07) fixed this issue. Please download and install the latest version.

**OLD ANSWER:**

Mainly the reason was that Command Line Tool 8.3 is not compatible.

According to the solutions from https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19734:

- Remove `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` first, download and install Command Line Tool 8.2 from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?name=Xcode

OR

- use `-ldflags -s` option for compilation or run

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot @JimB

I uninstalled the Xcode and it runs fine now. Weird !